# FBConnect and iPhone: logout and log in as different user, then execute FQL query

Tags: iphone, fbconnect

Has anyone had problems with the following?

I login as user A and get a bunch of data via FQL. All is working well.
Then, without closing the app, I logout, and login as user B. The iPhone confirms that I am user B and not A. However, once the FQL query is executed for user B, it just "hangs"... e.g. `-(void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result` is never called back.

Thanks.